# Calculating two columns at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, grouping, summarizing

Is it possible to calculate two columns at once?

So what I mean is that we have different covers and lengths and I want a total length of `"Cover A"` after that a total length of cover tb and so on.

See that attached photo for the columns that I mean.

[image]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

QGIS has an algorithm for that :

- Statistics by categories ([official documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html?#statistics-by-categories))

You have to select your layer, your category field (here `"Cover"`) and the field to calculate statistics (here `"Length"`). It will create a new non-geographic layer with your categories and some new statistic fields as minimum, maximum, mean, sum, etc.

---

You can also do a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` with a SQL query :

```sql
SELECT
    "Cover",
    SUM("Length") AS total_length
FROM
    your_table_name
GROUP BY
    "Cover"
```